# stubbing a method call in phpunit in a wordpress project

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to understand how phpunit is working and how to apply phpunit to my wordpress projects.

I am able to run the official wp-tests suite of wordpress and also i made some simple test with my wordpress plugins code.

Now I'm stuck on trying to use the so called "stubbing". php manual says: *The practice of replacing an object with a test double that (optionally) returns configured return values
is refered to as stubbing*.

i just made a sample like the one on phpunit manual but once I'm calling the **getMock()** method I have always a fatal error

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method SampleMockTest::generate()**

I'm working on

- windows 7
- XAMPP 1.7.7 with PHP: 5.3.8
- PHPUNIT 3.7.5
- phpstorm as IDE

code for file some-class.php

```
<?php

class SomeClass {

  public function doSomething() {
    return true;
  }

  public function doSomethingElse() {
    return true;
  }

}
?>
```

code for file samplemock.php

```
<?php

require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-plugin-dev\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\secure-attachments\lib\some-class.php';

class SampleMockTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function test_sample_mock()
  {

    $stub = $this->getMock('SomeClass');

    $stub->expects($this->any())
        ->method('doSomething')
        ->will($this->returnValue('foo'));

    $this->assertEquals('foo', $stub->doSomething());

  }
}
?>
```

I read a tons of blogs and questions but I was not able to understand where is the problem and at least how to investigate it. I lost one day struggling on this without results.

the error once I start the test I have the error below

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method SampleMockTest::generate() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-plugin-dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-mock-objects\src\Framework\MockObject\Generator.php on line 224**

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved simply updating the phpunit version. now I installed the latest version fo 3.7.* (3.7.37) and the code above is working like a charm.

I'm not installing the latest version of PHPUnit (4.*) since it has some issue working with the phpstorm IDE, that probably can be solved in some way but now I'm focused on phpunit :)

**So the trick was simply the PHPUNIT version. I saw that the mock feature was introduced earlier than 3.7 so I thougth that 3.7.5 was not the problem but I was wrong! PHPUnit 3.7.37 works ok with the code above**